# Skipping a line with getfile

Tags: c++

For my program, we are supposed to read a text file and print it to screen.  In the text file the message may looks like:

```
#email
mailservice
birdman
Intro 
Hello Birdman! Welcome!
#email
Frank
birdman
Hello
Hello Birdman, how are you?
```

I need to skip over the #email so that it prints out as:

```
From: mailservice
To: birdman
Subject: Intro 
Message: Birdman! Welcome!

From: Frank
To: birdman
Subject: Hello
Message:Hello Birdman, how are you?
```

This is the code that I have:

```
std::string filename1 = GetInboxFile(username);
std::ifstream fin(filename1);
std::string word;
std::cout << "\n";

std::string formatted = FormatEmailString("From: ", "To: ", "Subject: ", "Message: ");
//FormatEmailString is a function

std::cout << formatted;

while (fin.eof() == false)
{

    std::string line = GetLine(fin);

    if (fin.eof() == false)
    {

        std::cout << line << std::endl;

    }//END IF STATEMENT

}//END WHILE LOOP

std::cout << std::endl;
fin.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (fin)
{
    std::string line = GetLine(fin);

    if (fin) // @DietmarKühl: checking if the input was successful 
    {

        // if (line.find("#email") != std::string::npos) 
        if(line == "#email\n") 
        {
             line = "\n"; // you want a empty line instead 
             // continue; // you could use continue to simply skip it
        }

        std::cout << line << std::endl;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `stream.eof()` as the only condition is always wrong. You'll always need to test _after_ reading to determine if the read was successful.

Comment: It seems the code still use `fin.eof()` to check rather than checking if the input was successful which is done using `if (fin)`. Although reading line has no failure reason other than end of file, other input operations can fail without setting `fin.eof()` to `true`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is it OK now?

Comment: One part, yes. However, it is still not quite right to check the overall loop using `fin.eof()`. The `eof()` function is really only useful to determine if another read attempt was due to having reached the end of the stream.

Comment: I think it's a bit overkill for this beginner project. So the ultimate solution would be to use while(fin.eof() == false && fin) ?

Comment: The "ultimate solution" would check whether input was successful _after_ reading input and _before_ using results. Checking for success could just use the stream (like `if (fin)`). I find it convenient to do the inputs in the condition (see my answer).

Comment: You loop reads `while (fin.eof() == false)`. You do check after your input but if the loop contains inputs which may fail for other reasons than reaching the end of the stream (e.g., when the input gets amended to read an integer), it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Please tell me what to change and stop being unclear! With `while (fin.eof() == false && fin)` will that be OK?

Comment: Just use `while (fin)` (assuming you still check in the loop that input is successful after having read the input as you currently do).

Answer (score 1):

If the input file contains only the valid data, and we do not need to check it out, then we can get the right output as follows:

```
while (getline(fin, lineFromFile)) {

    if (lineFromFile.find("#email") < 40000) {
        getline(fin, lineFromFile);
        cout<<"From: "<<lineFromFile<<endl;
        getline(fin, lineFromFile);
        cout<<"To: "<<lineFromFile<<endl;
        getline(fin, lineFromFile);
        cout<<"Subject: "<<lineFromFile<<endl;
        getline(fin, lineFromFile);
        cout<<"Message: "<<lineFromFile<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `stream.eof()` as the only condition is always wrong. You'll always need to test _after_ reading to determine if the read was successful.

Comment: Even if it only contains valid data, using `eof()` is the wrong approach. Notably, when there is no more data, `eof()` is likely to be `false` before the read (when the file ends with a `'\n'` character). You need to check the stream state _after_ reading, e.g., using `while (std::getline(in, linFromFile))`.

Comment: My program displays data only when we found #email. After #email in valid code we must have at least 4 line, and this lines will be displayed. If I will receive '\n' character in lineFromFile or something else instead my if block, and so what? If I nothing to do with this data??

Comment: Your code may work correctly on data which happens to be well-formed. That constraint is essential to your code, though. In practice, I have yet to see a case where files are always well-formed (and I'm working as a developer since a few decades). The `eof()` flag is intended to determine if another error is possibly due to having reached the end of a stream. It is not intended to determine if things will be successful.

Comment: I never claimed to be the best solution. It is question for beginner and my answer for the beginners. By 'valid data' I mean and well-formed data too.